# In Swift why is char * becoming UnsafePointer<Int8>?

Tags: c, swift

I have added files containing Objective-C classes from another project into my Swift project. In one of these Obj-C classes, there is a data member called "decodedBuffer" of type char *. I'm not well-versed in C, but I thought that a char pointer was C's way of representing a String. When I try to get this data member while in my Swift code, for instance by writing the following line

```
myObjCClass.decodedBuffer = "a new value"
```

I get an error saying decodedBuffer is of type `UnsafePointer<Int8>`. So I have two questions:

1. Why is a char * a `UnsafePointer<Int8>` in Swift? If anything I would expect it to be `UnsafePointer<CChar>`.
2. How do I work with this value in Swift? The library I'm using is kind of a black box, as well as being completely in Objective-C, and so I'm not 100% how the data I pass by assigning a value to decodedBuffer will be processed. Any tips on how to interface with C objects in Swift? Yes I have read the "Interacting With C API's" portion of the Swift docs, but I would like some user-gained wisdom on interfacing with C API's if possible.

Comment: The UnsafePointer is just a way to warn developers that you are working with raw pointers, which are something that Swift would like to keep hidden to the developer itself as much as possible. It's not unsafe per se, take a look here for the interoperability: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Comment: "If anything I would expect it to be UnsafePointer<CChar>." `CChar` is a type alias for `Int8`

Comment: In C the type `char` is actually a synonym for 1 byte. The name `char` comes from an age when all strings in programs were ASCII and therefore every character had only 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Swift, in C you can declare mutable (var) or immutable (let) variables.

Your C library is passing you an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` = an immutable value.

One way to get your solution is to access the C code you can change it a mutable value. Then you can deal with the:  UnsafeMutablePointer = a mutable value.

Your second question about why is it represented as an < Int8 > type gets to the heart of pointers in C.  You don't pass around strings of data into different memory locations.  You pass the pointer.  The pointer points to the memory location of the first character of the char array (the string) held within memory.   Much more efficient.

A Swift example to show the int value of a C pointer:

```
let greeting: String = "Hello World."
let greetingPointer = strdup(greeting) // UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?
print("I am your \(greetingPointer).  I point to memory location of Greeting.")
```